# powershell csv output displays format in number instead of text

Tags: powershell

I have a script that outputs the numbers in CSV file(csv-export). By default, the csv are displayed in text format. Can powershell change the display format to number instead of text?

Answer (score -1):

Not currently, but I'm aware that it'll be possible soon, when PowerShell Team will make available the cmdlet `Out-3DPrinter` when you'll be able to get a number in 3 dimensions. Unfortunately, we have to wait.